# When using Referrer-Header: no-referrer, how to resolve relative URL's from within nested pages?

Tags: http, webserver, referrer, http-referer, helmet.js

Let's say I've got a page at www.example.com/pages/page.html and page.html has relative script/link url's.  The way I would normally know to serve /pages/js/page_js.js or /pages/css/page_css.css is to check the "referrer" header to see that it was http://www.example.com/pages.  Otherwise my relative script which looks like: `<script src="js/page_js.js"></script>` would actually resolve to /js/page_js.js on my server.

Referring to the documentation of [helmet.js](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/referrer-policy/) there's a security recommendation which involves blocking the browser from sending the `referrer` header.  If I were to implement this, well then how could I resolve the assets without knowing which path to resolve them to?

Answer (score 1):

If *example.com/pages/page.html* looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

  <script src="js/a.js"></script>

  <script src="/js/b.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The browser knows how to turn this into two requests: one to *example.com/pages/js/a.js* and the other to *example.com/js/b.js*. The `Referer` header isn't too relevant in this case.

(PS: I maintain Helmet, so if any of that documentation is unclear, let me know!)

Comment: Thank you Evan.  I'm not ignoring this, just waiting for a chance to test this and give this post the attention it deserves!